# Identify polygons with multiple attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I'm trying to identify polygons that contain both of two different land cover types from the same landcover layer. I cannot figure it out. Ive tried combinations of select by attribute and select by location, to no avail. I've also tried to intersect and query based on a single layer, but still no luck. At this point i'm sure it's something fairly simple and i'm going to kick myself once i know the answer.

I'm using ArcGis 10.4.1

Comment: So, you have a feature class in a geodatabase that have multiple attributes. Do you want to select those polygons that have Attr1 = X and Attr2 = Y? Or do you have other feature classes you need to use to retrieve the features needed? Please elaborate.

Comment: So, you have a land cover polygon layer, and you want to select certain polygons that have two specific land over types? Is that correct? A picture of the data, or examples of what you have tried would help. However, you could try: `SELECT * FROM layerName WHERE fieldName = "landcoverType1" and fieldName = "landcoverType2"` This is assuming the attributes aren't in the same field.

Comment: Add integer field to Landover, enumeration of classes. Intersect with polygons. Summarise result: polygon id = case, statistics=range of N. If statistics>0, multiple classes found inside polygon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "definition query" for your attribute data. You right click on the dataset that contains the attribute or a spatial data, then you click on "properties", select "definition query" from the menu tab. Go to code builder, and query. This will limit the data you have, so you can easily select your data to polygon.

IN CODE BUILDER

SELECT * FROM LAYERNAME WHERE FieldName = "landcoverType1" and FieldName = "Landcovertype2".